# get_user(uid).email returns None if user is logged in by facebook in firebase_admin django

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin.auth import get_user

cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

verified = auth.verify_id_token(id_token=token)
print(get_user(verified["uid"]).email)
```

output of this code will be None if user logged in with facebook, but if user is logged in with google then it will return email of user

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be explained simply. If user is logged in with Google, it sets uid to the user (uid and user is associated with each other). It's important to note that Google uid and user is associated with each other. On the other hand once user signs in with Facebook, FB uid and user is associated with each other.

So once user authenticates using FB, who was registered using Google, and you pass FB uid to Google get_user method, which waits only Google's one, this happens, because FB and Google have different types of uid which identifies user.

I hope, I made it clear. I think first you should define the authentication source and based on that, you should call specific authentication method, which will retrieve user based on authentication source and uid of the user.